# Algorithm for highest value in a semi-sorted array, where complete binary search is not possible?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

We're given a semi-sorted array:
(1, 2, ..., n, 1, 2, ..., n-1)
We know the maximum value in the array will be n, and for simplicity sake we know when we overshoot it (let's say checking that value will print/write a statement, or something along those lines).

2 scenarios:

1. If we overshoot the index of n, we are NOT allowed to overshoot again (except for the very last time so we know we're at the maximum value).
2. If we overshoot the index of n, we are allowed to overshoot it once more, and then we are not allowed to overshoot anymore (except for the very last time so we know we're at the maximum value).

We want this done using the least amount of steps in the worst case (preferably calculate the # of steps). And we want option 2 to use asymptotically fewer steps than option 1 (preferably calculate the # of steps).

Initially, I thought of the following:

1. Start at i=1
2. i=2i until overshoot
3. linear search from 1/2i to 2i-1, until we hit the maximum value (we would know by overshooting by one).

I thought this would be a O(logn) algorithm, but it actually appears to be O(n). This is because it's not like a binary search where we're able to continue until the end, because we must stop when we overshoot.

Now, I've thought about using exponents:
1. Start at i=1
2. i^2, if didn't overshoot then i=i+1, continue at this step until overshoot
3. linear search from  (i-1)^2 to (i^2)1 , until we hit the maximum value (we would know by overshooting by one).

This seems like it would be  O(n^1/2) , but when calculating the exact # of steps it seems like it would actually still be O(n), because the linear search could still be very large for high n.

For the second part, I thought about doing the same algorithm but using i^3.

1. Start at i=1
2. i^3, same as above
3. If overshoot then switch to i^2, same as above

....

I thought this would give O(n^1/3) .

Multi-part question:

1. Can these algorithms be improved so that we perform a minimum # of checks in the worst case?
2. Am I correct about the algorithmic complexity being O(n^1/2) and O(n^1/3) If so, what would the exact # of steps be, because it seems like that step ruins this?

Comment: http://datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, this looks interesting. I think one important distinction is that I wouldn't know the maximum # of floors (I know there is a max #, but it could be a 1 million floor building). This might have some affects on the algorithms.

Comment: Have you tried using `pivotedBinarySearch`? @ser120920

Comment: I actually didn't read the problem, but maybe it can help you...

Comment: @user120920 If you don't know the size of the array, then you can't possibly do better than linear since that is the required work to find out how big the array is.

Comment: Maybe I'm being obtuse, since everyone else seems to understand your question, but . . . if you know your array is (1, 2, ..., n, 1, 2, ..., n-1), then don't you already know that the desired index is n? Why do you need to try anything, risk overshooting anything, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The question of the optimal answer for `n` is hard.  But finding the maximum number that can be done with `k` tests is much easier.

Let `f(m, k)` be the maximum size of array where you can locate the max with at most `m` overshoots and testing at most `k` numbers.  Then the following statements hold:

1. `f(m, 0) = 1` (with 1 option I know where the max is)
2. `f(0, k) = k+1` (start at the beginning and go until you find it..if you fail in `k` tries then it is the last one you didn't look at)
3. `f(m+1, k+1) = f(m, k) + 1 + f(m+1, k)` (Test the `f(m, k) + 1`'th number, then do the appropriate thing depending on whether you overshot.)

It turns out that `f(1, k) = k*(k+1)/2`.  From there they get messy.  But for fixed `m`, you can show that `f(m, k) = km/m! + O(km-1)`  Which verifies your guess about `O(n1/2)` and `O(n1/3)`.